# How to implement the Hoare partition scheme in Quickselect?

Tags: python, quicksort, partition, quickselect

I try to implement the [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) as a part of a Quickselect algorithm but it seems to give me various answers each time.

This is the `findKthBest` function that finds the Kth largest number in an array given an array (`data`) and the number of elements in it (`low = 0`, `high = 4` in case of 5 elements):

```py
def findKthBest(k, data, low, high):
    # choose random pivot
    pivotindex = random.randint(low, high)

    # move the pivot to the end
    data[pivotindex], data[high] = data[high], data[pivotindex]

    # partition
    pivotmid = partition(data, low, high, data[high])

    # move the pivot back
    data[pivotmid], data[high] = data[high], data[pivotmid]

    # continue with the relevant part of the list
    if pivotmid == k:
        return data[pivotmid]
    elif k < pivotmid:
        return findKthBest(k, data, low, pivotmid - 1)
    else:
        return findKthBest(k, data, pivotmid + 1, high)
```

The function `partition()` gets four variables:

- `data` (a list, of for example 5 elements),
- `l` (the start position of the relevant part in the list, for example 0)
- `r` (the end position of the relevant part in the list, where also the pivot is placed, for example 4)
- `pivot` (the value of the pivot)

```py
def partition(data, l, r, pivot):
    while True:
        while data[l] < pivot:
            #statistik.nrComparisons += 1
            l = l + 1
        r = r - 1    # skip the pivot
        while r != 0 and data[r] > pivot:
            #statistik.nrComparisons += 1
            r = r - 1
        if r > l:
            data[r], data[l] = data[l], data[r]
        return r
```

Right now I simply get various results each time and it seems that the recursion doesn't work so well (sometimes it ends with reaching max-recursion error), instead of giving a constant result each time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hoare partition scheme normally uses the middle element as pivot. The first scans depend on element == pivot to stop them if there are no "out of place" elements detected. Otherwise bounds checks to prevent scanning beyond the ends of a sub-array are needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, there appears to be an mistake in the function  `partition()`

If you compare your code with the one in wiki carefully, you will find the difference. The function should be:

```
def partition(data, l, r, pivot):
    while True:
        while data[l] < pivot:
            #statistik.nrComparisons += 1
            l = l + 1
        r = r - 1    # skip the pivot
        while r != 0 and data[r] > pivot:
            #statistik.nrComparisons += 1
            r = r - 1
        if r >= l:
            return r

        data[r], data[l] = data[l], data[r]
```

Second, for example:

- You get an array `data = [1, 0, 2, 4, 3]` with `pivotmid=3` after partition
- You want to find the 4th largest value (`k=4`), which is 1

The next array `data` parsing to `findKthBest()` will become `[1, 0]`. 
Therefore, the next `findKthBest()` should find the largest value of the array `[1, 0]` :

```
def findKthBest(k, data, low, high):
    ......

    # continue with the relevant part of the list
    if pivotmid == k:
        return data[pivotmid]
    elif k < pivotmid:
        #Corrected
        return findKthBest(k-pivotmid, data, low, pivotmid - 1)
    else:
        return findKthBest(k, data, pivotmid + 1, high)
```

Comment: Thanks! However during the while loops l and r get values that are larger than the places in the list so it gets an IndexError while trying to check data[l] < pivot or data[r] > pivot